# Padding for blinded messages?

Tags: padding, blind-signature, blinding, pkcs1

I have a message $m$ that I wish to send as a blinded message for approval (a signature) to then unbind and use as authority.

Should I preform the procedure like so:

1. pad $m$ using EMSA-PSS (encrypting it)
2. then blind the now padded $m$ using RSA blinding
3. then have the signer sign using RSASSA-PSS and then send it back - Also, should the signer check the message before signing it to make sure it hasn't already been signed?
4. then upon receiving the now signed blinded padded $m$ back, sender unblinds the $m$ according to RSA Blinding
5. decrypt the unblinded $m$ using RSAES-OAEP
6. verify the signature, before using the now signed $m$ further in the process.

Comment: 1) I'd use full-domain-hash, not PSS. OAEP doesn't make any sense at all, this isn't encryption. 2) A blind signer cannot apply any padding.

Comment: hmm, ok why would you say FDH over EMSA-PSS. I think FDH would be simpler to implement, but I felt that EMSA-PSS would be more secure.

Is RSASSA-PSS the correct approach for the signing? Could a RSA blind be signed by other standards such as ECDSA?

Comment: FDH is simple and secure and leaves little room for the attacker to manipulate the padding. I'm not sure if PSS is designed to be used with blind signatures where an attacker chooses the salt.